# How to retrieve datatable row and display in an modal dialog for edit

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, datatable

I have a datatable, i want to be able display dialog for edit with the corresponding row values using Jquery or any other means, i have tried the code below, i have done a few researches online, yet no luck, i will appreciate if anyone could give a guide, assist or suggest on how to achieve this

My Table:

```
<pre> <table id="tblAppointment" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Matric/RegNo</th>
                        <th>Patient's Name</th>
                        <th>Visit Date</th>
                        <th>Appointment Date</th>
                        <th>Reason(s)</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="hidden-xs">
                                @item.MatricRegNo
                            </td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs">
                                @item.PatientName
                            </td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs">
                                @item.EntryDate
                            </td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs">
                                @item.AppointmentDate
                            </td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs">
                                @item.Reasons
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <span class="btn btn-info btn-sm edit" style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-Edit"></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
```

My Modal Dialog:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-Edit">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Appointments</h4>
                        </div>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm())
                        {                                
                            <div class="modal-body">

                                <div class="form-horizontal">
                                    <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                                        <label id="lblAppointmentIdEdit" class="control-label col-md-2">AppointmentId:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                            <input type="text" value="" id="AppointmentIdEdit" name="AppointmentIdEdit" class="form-control appointmentIdEdit" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label id="lblPatientRegNoEdit" class="control-label col-md-2">RegNo:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                            <input type="text" value="" id="patientRegNoEdit" name="patientRegNoEdit" class="form-control patientRegNoEdit" />

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label id="appointmentDateEdit" class="control-label col-md-2">Date:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepickerEdit'>
                                                <input type='text' class="form-control datetimepickerEdit" id="appointmentDateEdit" name="appointmentDateEdit" value="" />
                                                <span class="input-group-addon datetimepicker-addonEdit">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label id="lblReasonsEdit" class="control-label col-md-2">Reason(s):</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="reasonsEdit" name="reasonsEdit" class="form-control reasonsEdit"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        }
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" id="UpdateButton" name="UpdateButton" class="btn btn-primary update">Update</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Jquery Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.edit').on('click', function () {
    var myModal = $('#modal-Edit');
    var AppointmentIdEdit = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.AppointmentIdEdit').html();
    var matricRegNo = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.MatricRegNo').html();
    var appointmentDate = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.AppointmentDate').html();
    var reasons = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.Reasons').html();

    $('.appointmentIdEdit', myModal).val(AppointmentIdEdit);
    $('.matricRegNoEdit', myModal).val(matricRegNo);
    $('.datetimepickerEdit', myModal).val(appointmentDate);
    $('.reasonsEdit', myModal).val(reasons);
myModal.modal({ show: true });
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve using the Jquery function below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".edit[data-target='#modal-Edit']").click(function () {
    var columnHeadings = $("thead th").map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    columnHeadings.pop();
    var columnValues = $(this).parent().siblings().map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    var myModal = $('#modal-Edit');
    $('#AppointmentIdEdit', myModal).val(columnValues[0].trim());
    $('#patientRegNoEdit', myModal).val(columnValues[1].trim());
    $('.appointmentDateEdit', myModal).val(columnValues[4].trim());
    $('#reasonsEdit', myModal).val(columnValues[5].trim());
    //console.log("Column Values: " + columnValues[5]);

    myModal.modal({ show: true });
    return false;
});
$('.modal-footer .update').click(function () {
    $('form[name="modalForm"]').submit();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

make a javascript function and on click get all the values that you need to display on modal.
different methods you can apply on this.
using .val(), .attr() you can get the value and append on the modal using javascript.

Comment: Can you show an example, or a link to where i can read it up?